# Does the naming of keys in `$_SESSION` affect security?

Tags: php, security, session

I was wondering if the names of keys matters in term of security. Will a unique name be more secure than a generic one?

If I stored the user's email in
`$_SESSION['email']` would it be better if it was unique per user like `$_SESSION['em_10lettersID']`. Maybe it is not even safe to store the email in a session in general though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are talking about the name of the *session variable*, not the *session*.
- No, it does not matter. Anyone can open up their browser and check on the resources in their debugger and see what's stored in the cookies. Whether you call it "asdfkjh234690hj" or "email" won't matter if the value stored is "joe@example.com".

In general, it is not a good idea to store the email address or any other sensitive information in a session. It is best to store a user token (something like an MD5 hash or AES-encrypted secret string) which can be looked up in your database (or in flat files outside of the web root - inaccessible to the public www user either way). Your database or datastore could then use that key to retrieve the values you need to get into your code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: *"In general, it is not a good idea to store the email address or any other sensitive information in a session."*  You mean cookie?

Comment: Yes, cookies too. But the OP wasn't asking about cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Lets clear up any misconceptions.

A *session* is server-side storage. Nothing more than that. This storage is associated with a device ("user", if you will) by storing a *cookie* on the device that contains a unique *token*. Each request, the device sends this cookie (and thus the token) to the server. The server then recognizes the token and checks whether an existing *session* exists for this token. It loads the session from storage (by default this storage is a file) and its contents are stored in the `$_SESSION` variable.

By default, the name of the *cookie* is PHPSESSID, and the token is a randomly generated hash. You can inspect this cookie in the Chrome Developer Console under the Resources tab.

Now, since the session and whatever it contains is never exposed to the user (remember: it is persisted *on the server*), it does not matter what you store in it; the client cannot know.

The exception to this rule is when the client gains access to your server. However, when this is the case, you have larger issues to worry about.

One more thing to note is that `$_SESSION` is unique per client/user and they cannot affect each other's `$_SESSION`.

Beware that this explanation is somewhat simplified.

Now what you should NEVER do is store sensitive information in *cookies* (`$_COOKIE`). They ARE saved on the client/user!